# Controller doesn't read search_input, Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search

This is my search form:

```
  <%= form_tag("/kalender/:search_input", method: "get") do %>
      <%= label_tag(:search_input, "Suche:") %>
      <%= text_field_tag(:search_input) %>
      <%= submit_tag("search") %>
  <% end %>
```

This is my controller, getting the search_input:

```
@tag = params[:search_input]
if @tag.nil? || @tag.empty?
  @events = Event.all
else
  @events = Event.tagged_with("#{@tag}")
end
```

This is my route:

```
get "/kalender/:search_input" => 'kalender#kalender'
```

The problem seems to be, that this line: `Event.tagged_with("#{@tag}")` doesn't work.

When I run in the rails console this command: `Event.tagged_with("Metaphysik")`
2 Entries were found, it works as it should.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Edit: In the rails console:

```
irb(main):002:0> Event.tagged_with("Metaphysik")
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" WHERE (LOWER(name) = LOWER('metaphysik'))
  Event Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "events".* FROM "events" JOIN taggings events_taggings_65a1b36  ON events_taggings_65a1b36.taggable_id = "events".id AND events_taggings_65a1b36.taggable_type = 'Event' AND events_taggings_65a1b36.tag_id = 3
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Event id: 75, title: "Loigk", description: "p", user_id: 1, created_at: "2016-05-22 15:05:05", updated_at: "2016-05-22 15:05:05">, #<Event id: 76, title: "Metaphysik", description: "d", user_id: 1, created_at: "2016-05-22 15:52:30", updated_at: "2016-05-22 15:52:30">]>
irb(main):003:0>
```

Server, when typed in Metaphysiker:

```
Started GET "/kalender/:search_input?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search_input=Metaphysiker&commit=search" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-05-22 20:49:58 +0200
Processing by KalenderController#kalender as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search_input"=>":search_input", "commit"=>"search"}
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" WHERE (LOWER(name) = LOWER(':search_input'))
  Event Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "events".* FROM "events" WHERE (1 = 0)
  Rendered kalender/_fullkalendar.html.erb (3.2ms)
  Rendered kalender/kalender.html.erb within layouts/application (6.0ms)
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
Completed 200 OK in 294ms (Views: 169.1ms | ActiveRecord: 1.2ms)
```

Comment: What's the SQL generated when your controller runs `Event.tagged_with("#{@tag}")`?

Comment: @Uzbekjon I posted the SQL generated

Comment: Your controller is fine - problem lies with your routes

Comment: @Metaphysiker added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form ends up with the following action: `action="/kalender/:search_input"`. It has `:search_input` as the URL, literally. But you are expecting something like `kalender/your_input_string`.

Change your route to:

```
get "/kalender/search" => 'kalender#kalender'
```

And in your `KalenderController#search` action, access the search string with `params[:search_input]`.